# Execution of script.sed gives error in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, sed

I have a .sed script in which I have a code to make changes in a dataset. The code is as follows:

```
"s/,BEL,/,Belgium,/g" -e "s/,IT,/,Italy,/g"
```

However when I run it as follows I get the following error:

```
sed -f script.sed dataset.csv
```

```
sed: file script.sed line 1: Unknown command: '"'
```

Any idea of what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
"s/,BEL,/,Belgium,/g" -e "s/,IT,/,Italy,/g"
```

with

```
s/,BEL,/,Belgium,/g
s/,IT,/,Italy,/g
```